# How to replace string value in java/scala using regular expression

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here are some sample strings that I have in my dataframe column
(negative number and positive number)

Current Dataframe looks like this

```
| PID                |
|abc.PID-12345.cdf   |
|abc.PID-12345678.xyz|
|abc.PID123456789.abc|
|xy.PID12345.def     |
|ak.PID21.ab         |
```

My expected output is the following

```
+----------------------+
|      PID             |
+----------------------+
|  abc.PID999999999.cdf|
|  abc.PID999999999.xyz|
|  abc.PID999999999.abc|
|  xy.PID999999999.def |
|  ak.PID999999999.ab  |
+----------------------+
```

how can I use a regular expression to replace number to `PID999999999`?

I know `regexp_replace` can be used in the following

```
dataframe.withColumn("PID", regexp_replace(col("PID"), "regular expression", "999999999"))
```

What should be the correct `regular expression` pattern string?

Comment: Perhaps try: `.replaceAll("-\\d+|\\d+", "999999999")`.

Comment: thanks, @devilsHnd, this will work. However, I forget to point it out that PID might contain digit number. for example  abc1.PID-12345.cdf23,  so the above regular expression string will replace every number to "999999999".   I figured it out, we can do like this 
    .withColumn("RecipientID", regexp_replace(col("PID"), "(?<=PID)[^\\.]+", "999999999"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Thanks for all the feedback. 
`"-\\d+|\\d+"` would work when only only number present after PID. for example `abc.PID-12345.cdf`. but it will replace all number when PID look like `abc12.PID-12345.cdf22`

A more generic way is to do the following

`dataframe.withColumn("RecipientID", regexp_replace(col("PID"), "(?<=PID)[^\\.]+", "999999999"))`

Answer (score -1):

`regexp_replace` is probably what you're looking for. You can do something like this,

```
val df = ???
df.withColumn("PID",regexp_replace(col("PID"),"-\\d+|\\d+", "999999999"))
```

Hope this helped. Cheers

Comment: thank you so push for providing feedback. however, this regular expression string will replace every number to "999999999"